# Excel formula - auto sum for the same types

Tags: excel

I need a quick an simple excel formula to get the sum of values for different types of objects as listed below:

```
Type1  10 
Type1  10 
Type1  10 
Type2  10 
Type2  10 
Type2  10 
Type2  10 
Type3  10 
Type3  10
```

Number of items and number of types are unknown (long list), in a different worksheet I would like to get sum of types like:

```
Sumof Type1: 30
Sumof Type2: 40
Sumof Type3: 20
```

I need no VBA, just simple excel formula please..

BR

Comment: We are here to serve! Or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [sumif](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) is what you are looking for

Comment: Not if the number of types is unknown and potentially large, right?

Comment: you can get distinct lists using INDEX, MATCH and COUNTIF.  You aren't going to find a single formula which gives you everything you want with no effort.  You are going to have to figure some bits out yourself.

Comment: Interesting approach to a Q&A forum. If there's a solution for the sample given using that function, why not post it?

Answer (score 14):

Use a pivot table for this.

1. Add a header row to your data ("data type", "value")
2. Select your data
3. Insert pivot table
4. Drag "data type"-header to the Row Labels area
5. Drag "value"-header to the Values area
6. Make sure it says "Sum of value" and not "Count of value" in the Values area, if not you need to double-click it and change to use sum.

You could also use the "Add subtotals" feature for this, but pivot tables are more flexible and powerful.

Comment: This showed me what i was missing was moving the "value" column to be dragged into the "values area"

Answer (score 3):

```
  A        B
```

1      Type1          10

2  Type2        10

3  Type2  10

4  Type1  10

=Sumif(A1:A4,"=Type1",B1:B4)

Comment: Can you also add how to make a list with sums for Type1, Type2, Type3... like @Tolga asked?

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up like this.

[image]

=SUMPRODUCT(--(D1=A:A),--(E1=B:B),B:B)

So, basically . . .

```
To count Apples sales for North:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="north"), --(B2:B12="apples"))

or

=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12="north")*(B2:B12="apples"))

To sum Apples sales for North:
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12="north"), --(B2:B12="apples"), C2:C12)
```

See the link below for more details.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/08/24/excel-sumproduct-function-formula-examples/

Comment: Thanks! This is way easier to work with than the other answers.